# Why array doesn't print correct numbers?

Tags: c

Following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int izbaciSveProste(int n, int x[], int y[])
{
    int i;
    int flag=0;

    for(i=2; i<n/2; i++)
    {
        if(n%i ==0)
        {
            flag =1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(flag==1)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int i,j,n,x[100],y[100];

    printf("Koliko elemenata zelite u polju?\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("Enter elements in array:- ");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    scanf("%d",&x[i]);
    }

    int len = sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]);

    for(i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        if(izbaciSveProste(x[i]))
        {
            for(j=i; j<len; j++)
            {
                x[j] = x[j+1];
            }
            i--;
            len--;
        }
    }
    printf("Elementi nakon brisanja su:\n");
    for(i=0; i<len; i++)
        printf("%d\n",y[i]);

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Purpose of this program should be to delete all prime numbers from array x[] with n elements, remaining elements should be rewritten in array y[] and show count of elements in array y[] in the end.I believe that function is okay and  error is in main() specifically in storing y[].

Comment: Count number of arguments 
`int izbaciSveProste(int n, int x[], int y[])` it needs and how many you are passing `izbaciSveProste(x[i])`.

Comment: For the life of me I will never understand why people feel compelled to down-vote a question when they think the answer is too simple or obvious. Add some comments, an answer, maybe edit the title and be constructive.

Comment: Before questioning on SO people are expected to do some research that I'm not finding in OP's question(I'm not down voter)

Answer (score 2):

Your function prototype has 3 parameters:

```
int izbaciSveProste(int n, int x[], int y[])
```

When you call the function, you only provide 1:

```
if(izbaciSveProste(x[i]))
```

The compiler wants to get all 3.

As your function doesn't even touch the 2 array parameters, you might simply remove them from the function definition and only take 1 integer.

Another problem:
You print `y[i]` in your loop but you never assign any value to that array.

Comment: Is that really worth an answer? Better vote to close the question.

Comment: Its a legitimate question from a person who is clearly fresh to all this. So yes, an answer that is asked for non-nefarious purposes deserves an answer.

Comment: @Gerhardh same as I wrote earlier in comment, it prints empty array even if I entered purposely 2,3 prime numbers

Comment: @Arthuoff how do you enter "2,3 prime numbers"?  Also see my updated last paragraph

Comment: @Gerhardh randomly, let's say I want to enter 4 elements and I enter: 74, 6, 2, 3, then it should rewrite 2,3 to array y[] and print 2,3 and array y[] has 2 elements.I saw your last paragraph and I corrected my code.

Comment: I can't see where you put any prime number into `y` You only remove them from `x`.You need to store them before removing from the array. (And of course: You need an extra counter for the destination in `y` and only print as much numbers.

Comment: @Gernhardh What do you mean by store them, before removing from the array?

Comment: Well, how do you think, the numbers could get into `y` if *you* don't put it there? You need something like `y[dest] = x[i];` (Note: `dest` is an extra counter for `y`. You also mustn't use `len` as limit for printing your prime numbers.) That is a very basic concept of programming. If you plan to use a value later, you need to store it somewhere. It doesn't get assigned to a variable unless you provide the code for it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180275/discussion-between-arthuoff-and-gerhardh).

Answer (score 2):

Your function `int izbaciSveProste(int n, int x[], int y[])` requires three arguments. Your code `izbaciSveProste(x[i]` passes one argument. That's not much enough. The compiler tells you that fact with the error message:

> error: too few arguments to function 'izbaciSveProste'

Comment: Yeah this is correct, but still it won't print anything, even if I enter 2,3 prime numbers